# Plotting Time and Getting the Count in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, time

```
REGISTRATION_TIME
08:53:16
13:18:57
15:57:58
09:25:47
13:35:54
12:01:31
09:37:57
12:44:47
21:26:12
21:26:12
14:56:13
02:09:31
15:28:51
15:30:57
```

I am trying to plot the time on the X-axis and find the count for each time. This is a sample dataset of 5,000 rows. And would also like to create bins for every hour.

I tried the following:

```
TIME_plot <- ggplot(LW_Par, aes(REGISTRATION_TIME)) + geom_bar(colour = "white", fill = "#1380A1")
```

Having some trouble figuring out how to code this and any help would be much appreciated.

---

```
Time_Plot <- LW_Par %>%
  mutate(REGISTRATION_TIME = hms(REGISTRATION_TIME)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = REGISTRATION_TIME)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 24, colour = "white", fill = "#1380A1") + 
  scale_x_time() + bbc_style()
Time_Plot
```

So using the solution provided by H 1 (thank you), how would I go about expanding on the x-axis breaks to give more insight on where the counts are?

Also is there a way to use "summary" on the time data to find average or mode of dataset?

[image]

Comment: `ggplot(LW_Par, aes(x=REGISTRATION_TIME)) + geom_bar(stat = "count")`

Comment: Or get this dataset `data.frame(table(LW_Par))` and it should be easy to do whatever you desired with that. This is besides the fact that what you have already gives a barplot with frequency of each date. If you wanna make it more legible, then those are cosmetic features of ggplot, which you can easily find with a simple search. If you have a different question, then clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to use `geom_histogram` to easily bin the data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)

dat %>%
  mutate(REGISTRATION_TIME = hms(REGISTRATION_TIME)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = REGISTRATION_TIME)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 24) +
  scale_x_time()
```

[image]

Edit:

You can use the `breaks` argument in the `scale` command to set the number of x-axis labels.  You can also achieve finer control of the bins by using the `binwidth` argument in `geom_histogram`.  As you have a time variable, the unit represents seconds so you can bin by 15 mins, for example, by `binwidth = 900'.

```
dat %>%
  mutate(REGISTRATION_TIME = hms(REGISTRATION_TIME)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = REGISTRATION_TIME)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 900) +
  scale_x_time(breaks = hm(paste0(seq(0, 24, by = 3), ":00")))
```

Data:

```
dat <- read.table(text = "REGISTRATION_TIME
08:53:16
13:18:57
15:57:58
09:25:47
13:35:54
12:01:31
09:37:57
12:44:47
21:26:12
21:26:12
14:56:13
02:09:31
15:28:51
15:30:57", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Works perfect, also (2) more things. How would I be able to add more X-axis labels such as (12:00:00, 16:00:00) on the graph for a larger data set. And is there a way to use "summary" on the time data to find average or what times are most relevant

Comment: @DannyRamirez - See updated answer.  There are lots of ways to summarise the data.  You can already see what the approximate mode is using the graph.  If you want an explicit count by hour you can do something like `table(hour(hms(dat$REGISTRATION_TIME)))`.  The mean time of day can be calculated using `seconds_to_period(mean(period_to_seconds(hms(dat$REGISTRATION_TIME))))`.

Answer (score 0):

Minor variation of @H1's solution. You could do the time bucketing before ggplot:

```
library(dplyr); library(lubridate)
dat %>%
  mutate(REG_TIME_HOUR = hour(hms(REGISTRATION_TIME))) %>%
  count(REG_TIME_HOUR) %>%
  ggplot(aes(REG_TIME_HOUR, n)) + geom_col()
```

[image]